# Amazon S3 disable access of bucket root

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a AWS S3 bucket use to share file (with anyone, public access). So my bucket is set as public. Normally to access at this file you need the url but when you GET my bucket root you got a xml with index all my file. So I want to disable this xml and make my file private without the exact url, do you have a solution ?

Comment: What do you mean by "my bucket is set as public"? Did you create a Bucket Policy -- if so, can you show it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This bucket policy from the [Bucket Policy Examples](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-2) documentation page shows how to **Grant Read-Only Permission to an Anonymous User**:

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"AddPerm",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

They will be able to access files, but will not be able to list, delete or upload objects.

Comment: If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The permissions interface allows to to control this directly.

1. Open the root of the bucket in the management console. At the top,
   you should see several tabs. 
   [tabs interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiooY.png)
2. Click on the permissions tab. A set of
   four white buttons will appear.
3. Click on the 'Access Control List' button.
4. In the **Public Access** section, there will be a radio button with the 
   word **Everyone** next to it. Click it.
   [radio button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1z3y.png)
5. You get a dialog on the right. Make sure to uncheck the **List Objects** option. 
   [access to root list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S84YV.png)
6. Save and you're done.

If you try to look at your root, you should now see **Access Denied**
[Access denied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EK15T.png)

Answer (score -1):

Just head over to the AWS S3 console and select the file. You can change this files permission so that it suits your needs.

You could try it the other way around as well. Disable public bucket access and only make the files you want to share public. This should work as well.